# Firebase receiver within a third party library

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, intentfilter

I am developping an Android library (published in an aar file) aimed to be embedded within an Android application.

Since my library leverages on Firebase notification service, it defines two services (following Firebase implementation guidelines from Google) :

1. the first one extends `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and declares an intent filter for **INSTANCE_ID_EVENTS**.
2. the second one extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and declares an intent filter for **MESSAGING_EVENTS**.

In case the Android application hosting my library also relies on Firebase Notifications for its own execution, it implements these 2 services as well, with the same intent filters (**INSTANCE_ID_EVENTS** and **MESSAGING_EVENTS**).

When the same intent filter is declared by several services, only one of them is notified when the associated event occurs.

Therefore, with such configuration, the library and the hosting application are not both notified of Firebase related events. For exemple, if a **MESSAGING_EVENT** occurs only the `FirebaseMessagingService` of the library or the `FirebaseMessagingService` of the application is notified but no both of them.

Since the former implementaion of **GCM** notifications was relying on receivers (instead of services), **GCM** notifications could be received by both the library and the application.

Do you have an idea of how Firebase events can be notified to both the hosting application and the library?

Thanks a lot

**UPDATE**

The only solution I found constists in not implementing neither  `FirebaseInstanceIdService` nor `FirebaseMessagingService`in the library, thus no firebase related service is declared in library's manifest file. Instead I declared a WakefulBroadcastReceiver in the library with the following configuration :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.InnerFirebaseMessageReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I did not find how to 'hook' token update events the same way.

At the end, this solution enables to be notified of Firebase message reception events without interfering with the hosting application that can come with its proper Firebase service implementation. Firebase token updates won't be notified to the library but it can be acceptable since they are events that comes along with app reset.